# Mac Calendar has stopped allowing events to be entered on Sundays from month view?

Tags: macos, ical

Mac Calendar has stopped allowing events to be entered or viewed on Sundays from the Month view.  If I double click on a date on the month view, for a Sunday, nothing happens but if I go to the day view there is a default New Event on the day.

If I enter an event from the day view it does not appear on the Sunday in the month view.

Having been a Windows user for a long time I did wait to ask this question until I had turned the machine off for day and then back on the next day.

Is any one else experiencing this issue?
Is there a setting somewhere that got changed?

Comment: What does it do, or not do ?

Comment: Which Calender is that (google?)

Comment: I do use google calendar.

Comment: When you double click on a calendar date in month view you should get a new event on the calendar.  In the month view this does not appear.  I looks like nothing happened.  If I then go to the day view for that day the default new event item is there.  If I edit the or create a new event from the day view it does not show up in the month view.  This is only happening on the dates that are Sunday.  This is a new occurrence and has always worked fine in the past.

Comment: One thing that did happen just before this started to occur was that I got an email with an event date in it and i use the mac email client.  I clicked on the arrow in email next to the date to add it to the Calendar and that worked but it did not display in the month view.  Since then it has not worked.

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 1):

Quit iCal, and try removing the com.apple.iCal.plist file from your Mac

1. Open Finder
2. Go Menu, hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key and click on **Library**
3. Go to Preferences
4. Remove the **com.apple.iCal.plist** file or put .bak behind it (backup)
5. Logout or reboot your Mac and your problem should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I followed the instructions twice and the problem persists.